# Replace Massey Ferguson 360 tractor battery

Tags: battery, tractor

I've been looking for online resources on how to replace a 2018 Massey Ferguson 360 Tractor battery but could not find anything useful. We tried to do it ourselves by opening the side panel towards the front on the left, close to where the battery is located, but the opening was insufficient to reach the whole battery.

I would like help on how to do it or links to any resource that describes the process. I feel like it is a trivial process to call a mechanic.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!